# NSTimer not working calling UIButton setHidden:YES/NO

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa

I can't understand why this doesn't work. I'm trying to display lblstatus when the timer cycle is hit:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(TimeForPictureCycle)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
}

-(void)TimeForPictureCycle
{
    while(YES)
    {
        [lblStatus setHidden:NO];
        sleep(2);
        [lblStatus setHidden:YES];
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably a stupid question but its something I frequently overlook, have you set the reference in the XIB/Storyboard to the label?

Comment: Never call sleep on the main thread!

Comment: yes it its attached to IBoutlet and nib, I can setHidden without problems from any event

Comment: @phix23 I tried it from background but it doenst work either

Comment: Never call UIKit methods from a background thread!

Comment: This is simply going to freeze your app no matter what.. `while (YES), sleep?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calling `sleep()` on the main thread, that means after you set your label to `hidden` that thread pauses and prevents the run loop from continuing thus it's not able to update your UI. Your current code simple blocks your whole application.

What you could do is this:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.showTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(showLabel)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
}

-(void)showLabel
{ 
    [lblStatus setHidden:NO];
    self.hideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(hideLabel)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
}

-(void)hideLabel
{        
    [lblStatus setHidden:YES];
    self.showTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(showLabel)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.showTimer invalidate];
    [self.hideTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: thats better, but it can still cause problems: when viewDidAppear is called multiple times there can be multiple timers. better store the timer in an instance variable, so you can cancel it.

Comment: you could also do `[self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];` instead of using NSTimers

Comment: your right, i've updated my answer. I prefer to use `NSTimer` over `performSelector:` I don't know a specific reason, it's just a personal preference.

Comment: BTW you can also cancel performSelector: `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) object:nil]`

Comment: I know `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelector:@selector(hideLabel) target:self argument:nil];`  is another way to cancel it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [lblStatus performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:0 afterDelay:1];
    [lblStatus performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@1 afterDelay:3];
}
```

I'm not really sure why I can pass 0 as an object, but it works.

Comment: I like the simplicity, but that only executes once. The code in the question implies that it should run repeatedly.

Comment: Btw: you can pass the `0` because in this case it's treated as `nil`, so it will call `[lblStatus setHidden:nil]` which then again is treated as `[lblStatus setHidden:NO]`